# What causes TextView to vertical shift

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

What causes Text1 to shift vertically? The shift also depend on Text2 font size, and not depends on container, or text2 height.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="68sp"
        android:text="text2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: View aligned to the bottom of the layout. If you set `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to LinearLayout, then views will be centered. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i was expected left top, default position

Comment: it also not aligned to bottom, you can see its like 2/3 of linear-layout height, and this value changes only when text2 text-size changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, LinearLayout tries to align TextViews baselines (the bottom edge of the text).

To disable this behavior, add

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

to your LinearLayout